# SQL Server 2019 (Centos 8) Non-Yielding Scheduler

Tags: sql-server

**We are running SQL Server 2019 (Linux) CU4 with the following server specs...**

OS: Centos 8

RAM: 32GB

HDD: 1TB SSD

CPU: 8 Core I-7

SQL: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU4) (KB4548597) - 15.0.4033.1 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Linux (CentOS Linux 8 (Core))

**The SQL server becomes unresponsive after heavy loads (it appears) and has the following in the SQLDump file after a crash...**

2020-04-09 02:38:11.48 spid12s     AppDomain 3 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].2) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.

2020-04-09 02:38:11.48 spid12s     AppDomain 3 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].2) unloaded.

2020-04-09 10:09:43.60 spid31s     AppDomain 2 (master.sys[runtime].1) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.

2020-04-09 10:09:43.61 spid31s     AppDomain 2 (master.sys[runtime].1) unloaded.

2020-04-10 11:52:15.26 Backup      Database backed up. Database: readyalert, creation date(time): 2020/02/11(08:19:22), pages dumped: 190987, first LSN: 67110:336:1, last LSN: 67110:360:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'/var/opt/mssql/backup/readyalert_prod.BAK'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2020-04-10 11:52:15.28 Backup      BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 190746 pages in 4.842 seconds (307.765 MB/sec).

2020-04-12 00:00:02.54 spid59      [8]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.

2020-04-12 00:00:12.34 spid59      DBCC CHECKDB (readyalert) executed by NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 9 seconds.  Internal database snapshot has split point LSN = 00010627:00010e78:0001 and first LSN = 00010627:00010e68:0001.

2020-04-15 11:12:58.53 spid59      AppDomain 4 (mssqlsystemresource.dbo[runtime].3) created.

2020-04-15 11:16:28.21 spid88      AppDomain 5 (master.sys[runtime].4) created.

2020-04-15 14:39:02.71 Server      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      ***Unable to get thread context for spid 0

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * *******************************************************************************

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *   04/15/20 14:39:02 spid 384

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * Non-yielding Scheduler

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      *

2020-04-15 14:39:02.76 Server      * *******************************************************************************

2020-04-15 14:39:02.77 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x0000000000000338

**Any help would be appreciated as we tried updating to the latest CU4 and the problem still persists.**

Comment: I don't think SQL databases should be crashing in any circumstances. Make sure you are using the latest version of SQL Server. If the crash persists, try to contact Microsoft support and send them the crash dump.

Comment: Did you run this command "spid59 DBCC CHECKDB (readyalert) executed by NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" or it's just a log?

Comment: I am on the latest version of SQL 2019 CU4 but continue to experience this issue.  MS has been no help like usual...they said update to CU4 and it should fix it.  It did not.  Running out of options and will probably have to revert back to 2008 on Windows which had no issues.

Comment: Same here on latest 15.0.4043.16-4. Doesn't look like "memory pressure", swap empty, 19.6Gb used and 40Gb free, no iowait.
Load was 100% on one core and then load jumped to another core.